# Getting values of XML attributes In Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to Python and I need to fetch some of the attribute values from a XML file and then to convert these values to JSON.

example:

```
<messages> 
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Dont forget me this weekend!</body>
</messages>

{
"from":"Jani",
"body":"Dont forget me this weekend!"
}
```

How can I best achieve this? Would I convert it to JSON first? If yes, which library would I use? Lxml? Or would I convert it to String and then use regex to get some of the values?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [ElementTree API](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) to parse your XML text and get the desired values out of it.

Then you can use the [JSON API](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/json.html) to create the desired JSON output.

Answer (score 1):

I notice that your json format is just like a python dict.

```
from xml.dom import minidom

data = {}
with open('email.xml', 'r', encoding='utf8') as fh:
    dom = minidom.parse(fh)
# Get root element
root = dom.documentElement
for tag in root.childNodes:
    if tag.nodeType != tag.TEXT_NODE:
        key = tag.nodeName
        value = tag.childNodes[0].data
        data[key] = value
print(data)
```

Output is:
{'to': 'Tove', 'from': 'Jani', 'heading': 'Reminder', 'body': 'Dont forget me this weekend!'}

If u want to understand xml more deeply, some component you need to know, such as root, element, node, tag, attribute and so on.